# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib and Reason image not found

Tags: python, mysql, homebrew, mysql-python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Minor Project/xyz.py", line 5, in <module>
    import config
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Minor Project/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Users/brijeshlakkad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/brijeshlakkad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brijeshlakkad/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so
  **Reason: image not found**
```

When i install mysql using "*brew install mysql*", file will be executed. And when i executed brew install mysql, there are two different mysql both running separately. I executed this file, then al data are being stored in **local mysql** different from **phpmyadmin mysql**.

Comment: Are you actually using the long-dead connector `MySQL-python`, aka `MySQLdb`? If so, that only works with MySQL 5.x (and was only ever fully tested with 5.0). And are you using it on purpose? Or are you using one of the modern connectors like `pymysql` or `mysqlclient` that can be configured to install a drop-in replacement for `MySQLdb`?

Comment: Meanwhile, I don't understand the second half of your question at all, but if you've installed two different MySQL databases and you're connecting to the wrong one, that's probably an issue with your connect command, but without actually seeing the command you're using, and knowing how you set up the two databases, it's pretty much impossible to even begin to debug that.

Comment: after i executed "brew install mysql", two different mysql are created: 1. Cellar/mysql 2. Mamp mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: I don't know what "Mamp mysql phpadmin" means. But `brew install mysql` just installs one copy of MySQL, into `Cellar/mysql`, and then puts a bunch of symlinks into `/usr/local/bin` that link to that Cellar.

Comment: pymysql solved my prooblem thank you sir.

Comment: but it gives me Error of : raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: IIRC, the brew install of MySQL is configured to not allow root connections by default. But I may be wrong— at any rate, that’s a completely different problem, which probably already has good answers here, so you should search for one, or write a new question about it.

Answer (score 6):

For me running this command, for my Ruby & Rails project, fixed the issue

```
gem pristine mysql2
```

Answer (score 6):

Upon investigating I found that libmysqlclient.21.dylib is updated to libmysqlclient.23.dylib, and now libmysqlclient.21.dylib is not found. This case was investigated in macOS. Mac did updated mysql and mysql-client and both have libmysqlclient.*.dylib latest version. To map the current libmysqlclient.*.dylib uninstall mysqlclient and install new mysqlclient

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient

pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue because it looks like brew recently updated the current version of mysql to 8.2.

If you update your mysql version, you might get problems installing the mysql2 gem. I think the mysql2 gem needs some upgrades to handle the newer mysql version.

Something like this should get you going if you've upgraded (Ruby & Rails project)

brew install mysql@8.0

brew link --overwrite mysql@8.0

## Check the version

mysql --version

## Should be something like mysql  Ver 8.0.35 for macos14.0 on arm64 (Homebrew)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem, in a nutshell, is that you're trying to use the ancient `mysql-python` library, aka `MySQLdb`. That library was abandoned around the MySQL 5.1 days, so it doesn't support MySQL 6 and later, and you presumably have MySQL 8.0, so the shared library it's looking for doesn't exist, hence the `image not found` error.

Homebrew *does* include a `mysql@5.5` package, which I think has a dylib with the right name, which *might* be old enough to work with `mysql-python`, if you really want to go that way, but it isn't going to be supported. Or you can download MySQL 5.0 or 5.1 source and build it yourself (there are no Mac binaries of anything older than 5.6 that will run on a current macOS), and that will definitely work.

But a better solution is to use a library that's still maintained. Unfortunately, there are many choices out there, but I get the impression that most people use one of the three big ones:

- `mysqlclient` is a fork of `mysql-python`, which binds to current versions of the C libraries (`brew install mysql` or download the installer from the MySQL/Oracle website).
- `PyMySQL` is a rewrite in pure Python, which doesn't even need C libraries.
- `MySQL Connector/Python` is a new implementation written from scratch by MySQL/Oracle. (You probably want the Oracle installer with this one.)

`PyMySQL` is a much better drop-in replacement than `mysqlclient`, and it plays nice with everything else in the universe, and it's well-written code that's easy to debug if you have a problem… but it can be pretty slow. And unless you've got a whole mess of existing code to maintain, you usually don't need a perfect drop-in replacement, just something with a pretty-close `connect` call and support for all of DB-API 2, and `mysqlclient` covers that.

Answer (score 2):

### Fix for MacOS 14 - Sonoma

After a lot of searching and a difficult time I was able to find a possible answer for any MacOS user. If you are using Sonoma MacOS 14, please check @nickgoodwind's answer on issue [NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined after setting change to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63109987/7120471) where the same error happens

```
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(...)
```

Comment: I just ran into the same issue after upgrading my MacOS to Sonoma. Running `gem pristine mysql2` fixed it for my *Ruby on Rails* app.

Comment: Thansk @tintin81! That fixed my issue after updating to Sonoma.

Comment: Running "gem pristine mysql2" did NOT fix it for me. Instead i got a "make failed" error trying to build it.