# NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined after setting change to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

I have a running Django blog with sqlite3 db at my local machine. What I want is to

1. convert sqlite3 db to mysql db
2. change Django settings.py file to serve MySQL db

Before I ran into the first step, I jumped into the second first. I followed [this web page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database) (on MacOS). I created databases called `djangolocaldb` on root user and have those infos in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` like this:

```
# /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[client]
database=djangolocaldb
user=root
password=ROOTPASSWORD
default-character-set=utf8
```

Of course I created db, but not table within it.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| djangolocaldb      |
| employees          |
| information_schema |
| mydatabase         |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I changed `settings.py` like this as the web page suggested. Here's how:

```
# settings.py

...

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            'OPTIONS' : {
                'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
                }
            }
        }

...
```

Now, when I run `python manage.py runserver` with my `venv` activated, I got a brutal traceback like this(I ran `python manage.py migrate` first, and the traceback looked almost the same anyway):

```
(.venv) ➜  django-local-blog git:(master) ✗ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/py/coreyMS_pj/django-local-blog/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

So this `NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined` is the problem. I installed `mysqlclient` before, changed `settings.py`, made db in mysql, but none of the steps made it any helpful yet.

And I noticed that even I changed my `settings.py` back to sqlite3, my blog spit the same *_mysql not defined error*. So I ended up reverting my commit and now I'm back to sqlite3 (at least my blog is running with it).

I'm guessing it could be that I didn't convert data first, but I'm not 100% sure of it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you've installed the homebrew mysql client: `brew install mysql-client` so that libmysqlclient is available (the official MySQL C-library, that the pyhton extension makes use of).

Comment: @Melvyn Now that I had ran `brew install mysql-client`, I have different traceback. 'blah blah blah ...' and  `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value. ` Looks like I made some progress. I'll look into this now. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/)? Potentially not always a recommended path but it worked for my use case.

Comment: Working on Apple M1 the link mentioned by Jakob was key to getting this working.  Don't forget to add the lines to "fake" the version at the bottom of your Settings! https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So as a full answer:

If you use the python package [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) you still need to install the mysql client from Oracle/MySQL. This contains the C-library that the python package uses. To make things more confusing: the python package is in fact written in C for speed increases. To install this library on MacOS:

```
% brew install mysql-client
```

There's also a [pure python package](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/), with a more attractive MIT License, which can be a solution if your company or client does not allow GPL. However, it's not officially supported and some subtle bugs can occur in between releases. YMMV.

Comment: it didnt work for me still the same problem

Answer (score 24):

This did the job for me! Just install libmysqlclient-dev (`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` for Ubuntu). Sometimes, the lib files simply are missing even if you just installed mysql. :)

Comment: for other OS check requirements here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#install

Answer (score 21):

this worked for me:

**add this to PATH:**

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH"
```

Comment: do we add that to the .bash_profile? where do we add that?

Answer (score 20):

So, I'm answering my own question. Since my blog has database, I gave it a shot to make another project without db, start fresh.

What I noticed was there's a problem importing `MySQLdb` module(sub module of mysqlclient) with this traceback: `Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib`.

For browsing a few hours I realised that for some reason Mac security setting keeps this from being imported properly.

On `mysqlclient` library github I found [one issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/14#issuecomment-538783371) reporting the same as mine. It suggests I run `cp -r /usr/local/mysql/lib/* /usr/local/lib/`. After this I set `settings.py` for `django.db.backends.mysql`, ran `python manage.py migrate` and it worked. So for empty database, this could be a solution. Still struggling with database one though.

I use

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.6
- pyenv

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you have installed mysql client. To install it write following command.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Go to the settings.py file of your project and then import

```
import pymysql 
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

run the server
If you get no module named pymysql then in terminal run

```
pip install pymysql
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem on my MacOS (Big Sur) and I fixed it by doing this
`cp -r /usr/local/mysql/lib/* /usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 7):

On a MacBook Pro M1 macOS Monterey, running this command didn't work:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH"`

But this worked for me:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Comment: ```export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib```
works!

Comment: Nice! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This solved the issue for me:

Since Python3 is not able to connect with Python through mysqldb, you need to install an additional module to fix things. installing mysqlclient caused me to have the same `NameError: : name '_mysql' is not defined` problem.

However, by using `pymysql`, and adding the code line
`pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` at the top of my `Flask` app, I managed to get it running without any errors!

More info on [mysql modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724855/14022782)

Answer (score 6):

I'm using MacOS Sonoma and recently faced this issue.

I installed MySQL using homebrew. I checked the path where mysql was installed using

`brew info mysql`

Then I noticed that I has `libmysqlclient.22.dylib` instead of `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` which my app required. I had to create a symbolic link. In my case I had to run

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

Afterwards I had to add this to my path and it worked

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and it was working for a while. I did an update on MacOS BigSur then it stopped working with this error.

To fix this for me it was a simple uninstall reinstall of both django and mysqlclient.

The uninstall/reinstall of just mysqlclient itself did not do the trick. Also the order may help. Here are the commands in the order i did it in:

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip uninstall django
pip install django
pip install mysqlclient
```

Note: this will install the latest versions, so if you have specific versions, make sure you install those versions.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and couldnt find solution for hours

```py
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/{path-to-venv}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: /{path-to-venv}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: failed to map segment from shared object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/{path-to-venv}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

so if anyone here is like me and has the virtualenv on a mounted partition/disk, you have to mount it with *exec*, thats the whole problem.

Remount the partition with executable permission as explained in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311438/how-to-make-tmp-executable.

If you mount the drive with fstab, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/678857/fstab-doesnt-mount-with-exec.

(well, that was 10hours of trying and debugging well spend lol)

Comment: Had a similar issue. Running `pythonc -c "import MySQLdb"` was the simplest way for testing if it would work. My solution was to copy missing library files from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib{mariadb,mysqlclient}*` into my image.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with my django project working on ubuntu 22.04 but when i imported the code below to the setting file for the django project it works,

1. import pymysql
2. pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

it will only work if you have pymysql installed but if you don't have it installed used pip install pymysql.
This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions listed here and none of them worked for me.

My solution to this was to use a conda environment rather than a virtualenv. Just copy your environment to requirements.txt (for convenience) and make a new environment with conda.

1. pip freeze > requirements.txt (save your environment)
2. conda create -n django-env --file requirements.txt (create new environment)
3. pip install mysqlclient (if it wasn't already)

I was able to connect to my local mysql database and also my Amazon RDS database, no problem. I know this doesn't solve the issue directly. If you absolutely must use virtualenv this won't help.

I signed up for a Stackoverflow account just to share this. I hope it saves some other poor soul from 10 hours of "_mysql is not defined" hell.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Melvyn.

you can see your MySQL library link by typing like:

```
(quantum) chaiyudeMacBook-Pro:quantum chaiyu$ python
Python 3.8.7 (v3.8.7:6503f05dd5, Dec 21 2020, 12:45:15) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb as Database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

then type:

```
(quantum) chaiyudeMacBook-Pro:quantum chaiyu$ otool -L /Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
/Users/chaiyu/Envs/quantum/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so:
    /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib (compatibility version 21.0.0, current version 21.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
(quantum) chaiyudeMacBook-Pro:quantum chaiyu$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
ls: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib: No such file or directory
```

and then, I found the library MySQL linked to does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
brew install mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

for mac

## Assume you are activating Python 3 venv

```
brew install mysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

for ubuntu interminal run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
pip install mysqlclient
```

for # Red Hat / CentOS

```
sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending like decade on this issue found a good answer.

`mysqlclient` is a Python 3 compatible fork of the original Python MySQL driver, `MySQLdb`. It still provides a Python module called `MySQLdb`. On install, it compiles against either the MariaDB client library or MySQL client library - whichever one you have installed.

Solution Found [Here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/) By Adam(Genius Guy)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Silicon M1 Mac and a conda environment the only solution that worked for me was to use [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) installation, which is comparable to Miniconda, but with conda-forge as the default channel. There is an Apple Silicon option that solved the problem for me: https://github.com/Haydnspass/miniforge#download

(Solution from https://towardsdatascience.com/using-conda-on-an-m1-mac-b2df5608a141)

Comment: Please include pertinent code and resources from included links. This will prevent the answer becoming dead if the linked page goes away.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30635184)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, use:

```
open -t .bash_profile
```

and add the following:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH"
```

---

If you're using Zsh, use:

```
open -t ~/.zshrc
```

and add the following:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

although I used _mysql for 10 years, the MySQL website tells the recommended way for Python 3 at:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/preface.html

Conversion may take some time, but for me less than an hour. Here an example with new code:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='mensfort', password='zhongcan',
                              host='127.0.0.1', database='restaurant')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('select dongle from personnel')
for dongle in cursor:
    print(dongle)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Please use your own password, database name, queries, this is just an example.

Please do UNINSTALL this. This is not working for me:

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector
```

Please INSTALL this first. It works great:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

For Macbook M1 this command worked

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

M1 MacBook Pro with Ventura; working fine before then suddenly started getting this error.

TLDR:

`brew link mysql-client --force`

I'm not sure exactly why I started receiving this message but it was after I updated Mac OS to Ventura, did some Homebrew upgrades, and also updated Pycharm.

Checking the actual location of `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` and where it was being checked for showed that it simply wasn't checking the correct location.

Adding the correct location to `PATH` didn't fix it.

Copying the files from `mysql/lib/` to `/usr/local/lib/` would almost certainly fix it because I could see that location was being checked for the required file but that seems like kind of a workaround to me that might cause issues in the future...like if the package is updated in the future due to a security vulnerability but you don't notice and don't re-copy the updated files.

I could see the Homebrew directories were also being checked but Homebrew doesn't link this package by default.  Trying to link it (`brew link mysql-client`) showed a warning that this is a `keg-only` package and must be linked with `--force`.

Double-checking with `brew link mysql-client --force --dry-run` showed that the command would simply link the appropriate files and wouldn't be deleting anything.

So, I thought it would be safe to go ahead and and force link it and it did indeed fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install mysql
```

this is works for me

Comment: Please add an explanation of what this does and why it would help the person who asked the original question

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command

```
conda install -c conda-forge mysqlclient
```

it did it for me

Answer (score -2):

Reverting back from MySQL Server 8.x.x to 5.7.x worked for me.

> Django supports MySQL 5.5.x - 5.7.x. MySQL 8 and later aren’t supported.

Found @ [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#version-support)