# no such file libmariadb.3.dylib error when importing MySQLdb on mac M1

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb, homebrew

I migrated my data to M1 Monterey MacOS from intel macmini. I was happy to use django and mariadb **until I installed a package using homebrew**. I installed homebrew and installed vim with it, and then my django-mariadb connection suddenly stopped working.

I found out that the error was caused in python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py in 18th line in my venv.

```
try:
    from MySQLdb.release import version_info
    from . import _mysql  # this line causes the problem

    assert version_info == _mysql.version_info
except Exception:
    raise ImportError(
        "this is MySQLdb version {}, but _mysql is version {!r}\n_mysql: {!r}".format(
            version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
        )
    )
```

And the stacktrace goes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/revhat/basecamp/.venv/basecamp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/revhat/basecamp/.venv/basecamp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/libmariadb.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/revhat/basecamp/.venv/basecamp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/libmariadb.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmariadb.3.dylib' (no such file)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/gwanghyeongim/Documents/revhat/basecamp/.venv/basecamp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I had written [a post about '_mysql not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109987/nameerror-name-mysql-is-not-defined-after-setting-change-to-mysql) some time ago, and I fixed the problem by exporting a path in my `~/.zshrc`. But this time I googled the mysterious file `libmariadb.3.dylib`, but couldn't find satisfying results: most posts were about `libmysqlclient.21.dylib`.

I suspect this is due to homebrew on M1. As if to confirm my suspicion, there are [some issues](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues?q=m1) on mysqlclient github, and [a notable one](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/526) addresses similar problem, but the maintainer doesn't seem so much passionate in helping.

I installed and reinstalled brew, and even tried installing Rosetta2 homebrew following [this page](https://diewland.medium.com/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-macbook-m1-87c5b0fcb3b5), with no avail.

[Another homebrew issue page](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/569) unfortunately didn't help me much either.

My environment are as follows:

- python3.7.7 installed through [installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-377/)
- Apple M1 pro Monterey Version 12.0.01
- mysqlclient 2.1.0

Any help or thoughts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following only applys to those who use M1 chip**

In a nutshell

- Use Rosetta homebrew
- put `--no-cache-dir` when installing `mysqlclient`

**Before following the procedure below, make sure you delete native homebrew.**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

**and delete native homebrew setting in `~/.zprofile`**.

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Use Rosetta homebrew instead of native homebrew. This seems to cause the beginnig of nightmare.

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

When you type which brew, you will see a path starting from /usr/local/ like this

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

Now your brew is rosetta homebrew, instead of native homebrew.
Then go to your virtualal environment, reinstall mysqlclient, but with --no-cache-dir tag for install.

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient -y
pip install mysqlclient --no-cache-dir
```

Now try importing MySQLdb in shell. It shouldn't log any stacktrace this time.

```
python
>>> import MySQLdb
```

Now django won't have problem connecting to mysql or mariadb.

[This answer is also posted on mysqlclient issue.](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/496#issuecomment-1039802588)

---

This answer above omitted to reinstall mysql with rosetta homebrew, now that I look back. Make sure   to install mysql with rosetta homebrew. You can use alias to run rosetta brew in your shell config file: zshrc in my case.

```
alias ibrew="arch -x86_64 brew"
```

then run `ibrew install mysql` to install mysql with rosetta homebrew.