# I have installed mysqlclient , but not able to run server

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-runserver

I am a beginner in python and Django.
I would like to connect my Django project to MySQL database,I have installed mysqlclient

```
brew install mysql
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

but after changing the settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'storefront',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
    }
}
```

I get an error for running server: (NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined)

```
source /Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/bin/activate
(base) niloufar@Niloufars-MacBook-Air site-functions % source /Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/
site-functions-HFSltvjv/bin/activate
(site-functions) (base) niloufar@Niloufars-MacBook-Air site-functions % python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/niloufar/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/niloufar/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/niloufar/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 235, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/Users/niloufar/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/niloufar/.local/share/virtualenvs/site-functions-HFSltvjv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I have already checked the status of MySQL , and it is installed properly:

```
mysql -u root -p


Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.29 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Also I have added the directory of MySQL to the PATH

```
echo $PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
```

What's the problem then ?

Comment: Did you try `brew install mysql-client`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name '\_mysql' is not defined after setting change to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109987/nameerror-name-mysql-is-not-defined-after-setting-change-to-mysql)

Comment: I had installed mysql-client before , again run it. and No the link does not help .

Comment: @allexiusw
 I run 
`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.zshrc`      and       
`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH' >>~/.zshrc`    then    
`source ~/.zshrc`
but nothing changed

Comment: When I run `pip freeze` this is what I get :

`asgiref==3.5.1
Django==4.0.4
django-debug-toolbar==3.4.0
mysql==0.0.3
mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
mysqlclient==2.1.0
protobuf==3.20.1
sqlparse==0.4.2`

Comment: @Nilou99: This should help https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/. Instead of using myqlclient usepymysql package to talk to MySQL